# Objective-c - failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource

Tags: ios, tableview

I try to add cell programmatically, and I have in my table the following

```
 if (indexPath.section == AST_SF_SECTION_DATES) {

        if (indexPath.row == AST_SECOND_1) {

            cellIdentifier = @"DemoCell";
            if (cell == nil) {
            DemoCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
            cell = [[MY_BUNDLE loadNibNamed:cellIdentifier owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
            cell.label.text = @"I'm a label";
            }

        }
```

Also I have xib with reuse identifier inside attributes inspector, .m and .h file.

and I tried

```
[_tableView registerClass:[DemoCell self] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"DemoCell"];
```

inside viewDidLoad of view controller with table, but error still there

log is following

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3512.60.7/UITableView.m:7971
2016-06-11 13:55:13.768 SDKTemplate[14783:7920598] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView (<UITableView: 0x7ffb9c061c00; frame = (0 0; 375 667); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7ffb9acab350>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7ffb9ac92450>; contentOffset: {0, -64}; contentSize: {375, 492.60000000149012}>) failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource (<ASTSearchForm: 0x7ffb9ac9f8f0>)'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, if you want to add new cell programmatically, you should at first

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

second, in table view data source's `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you should return new cell correctly

Answer (score 0):

This line is incorrect, remove it:

```
cell = [[MY_BUNDLE loadNibNamed:cellIdentifier owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
```

`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath`[always gives you a fully formed cell](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:):

> A UITableViewCell object with the associated reuse identifier. This method always returns a valid cell.
>
> If you registered a class for the specified identifier and a new cell must be created, this method initializes the cell by calling its initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier: method. For nib-based cells, this method loads the cell object from the provided nib file. If an existing cell was available for reuse, this method calls the cell’s prepareForReuse method instead.

So remove that, and if anything still goes wrong, it's your registration at fault. We'd have to look at the class code and/or nib to see what exactly. But very likely just use what `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` gives you and you'll be good.